# why this word_dict = {word: None for word in word_list} so fast

Tags: python

this code work so fast

```py
with open('words.txt') as fd:
    word_list = fd.read().splitlines()


word_dict = {word: None for word in word_list}   
print(word_dict)

def find_rev_pairs(word_dict):
    for word in word_dict:
        if word[::-1] in word_dict:
            print (word, word[::-1])

find_rev_pairs(word_dict)
```

the problem in this line

```py
word_dict = {word: None for word in word_list}
```

**when I use it code work so fast if I use `word_list` directly code will be so slow**

Comment: What is "fast" and "slow" in your context? Please, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for word in X:
    if word[::-1] in X:
```

The above piece of code is O(N^2) if `X` is a list, but only O(N) if `X` is a dict or a set, so you can also use `set(word_list)` or `{word for word in word_list}`